# Power BI - Add N WorkDays to a Date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a calendar table that has a column storing Flag to Indicate if a calendar date is a BusinessDay (WorkDay).  WorkDay_FL = 0 means the Date is either weekend or Holiday.  I want to create a calculated column to add 5 working days to a given Date.

So if Date = 12/30/2020, i.e. 30-Dec-2020 then adding 5 WorkDays should give me 1/7/2020 (7-Jan-2021).

```
31-Dec-2020 = WeekDay
1-Jan-2021 = Holiday
2-Jan-2021 = Weekend
3-Jan-2021 = Weekend
4-Jan-2021 = WeekDay
5-Jan-2021 = WeekDay
6-Jan-2021 = WeekDay
7-Jan-2021 = WeekDay
```

Either a DAX formula or Power Query Function will work.

Thanks

Comment: This would be clearer if you posted exactly what your data looks like. Does the box contain your "Flag" column? Are the items in the box all in the same column?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a calculated table in your calendar table with a progressive number on working days. For instance, assuming that your WorkDay_FL is 1 for working days

```
WorkDayProg = 
VAR CurDate = 'Date'[Date]
RETURN CALCULATE( SUM('Date'[WorkDay_FL]), 'Date'[Date] <= CurDate, REMOVEFILTERS('Date') )
```

and the use the WorkDayProg calculated column to compute the future (or past) dates on working days only

```
FiveWorkingDaysInTheFuture =
VAR CurrentWorkDay =
    MAX( 'Date'[WorkDayProg] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        MIN( 'Date'[Date] ),
        'Date'[WorkDayProg] = CurrentWorkDay + 5,
        REMOVEFILTERS( 'Date' )
    )
```

we use MIN since the non-working days have WorkDayProg equal to the last working day.

Answer (score 0):

I used a **nested if statement** **without using a calendar or rank function to solve this**. I wanted to add 10 work days to my '**site visit end date**' column so I calculated the **NetworkDays** between 'site visit end date' and 'site visit end date'+**11 days**. If the answer is 10 days then it will add 11 days to the 'end date' column if not then in the next step I calculated the network days between 'site visit end date' and 'site visit end date'+**12 days**. Again if the answer is 10 it will add 12 days to the 'end date' column effectively giving me 10 network days between them if not then in the next step I calculated the network days between 'end date' and 'end date'+**13** and did the same till 'end date'+**14** days. Since if I try to find network days between a date dd/mm/yy and dd/mm/yy +15 days, the work days will always exceed 10 as in two weeks(i.e.14 days) 4 holidays can fall at max. Here is the formula-

WORKINDAY = IF(NETWORKDAYS('Monitoring Visit Report_3002'[Site Visit End Date], 'Monitoring Visit Report_3002'[Site Visit End Date]+11)=10,'Monitoring Visit Report_3002'[Site Visit End Date]+11,IF(NETWORKDAYS('Monitoring Visit Report_3002'[Site Visit End Date], 'Monitoring Visit Report_3002'[Site Visit End Date]+12)=10,'Monitoring Visit Report_3002'[Site Visit End Date]+12,IF(NETWORKDAYS('Monitoring Visit Report_3002'[Site Visit End Date], 'Monitoring Visit Report_3002'[Site Visit End Date]+13)=10,'Monitoring Visit Report_3002'[Site Visit End Date]+13,'Monitoring Visit Report_3002'[Site Visit End Date]+14)))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).